# Chekout multiple git repo into differrent folder and copy files/folders between them in Jenkins

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins & Docker. I have two separate projects in difference git repository.

- Asp.net Core WebApi project (name WebApi)

```html
Directory: C:\Work\WebApi


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                     
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                     
da----        24-May-17     13:28                docs                                                     
da----        29-May-17     09:09                WebApi                                           
-a----        24-May-17     17:04            150 .gitignore                                               
-a----        12-Jun-17     16:01           4166 build.sh                                                 
-a----        12-Jun-17     16:23              0 print.txt
```

- Reactjs project (name WebUI)

```html
    Directory: C:\Work\WebUI


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                        
da----        09-Jun-17     09:11                .vs                                                         
da----        12-Jun-17     11:48                build                                                       
da----        08-Jun-17     16:33                config                                                      
da----        05-Jun-17     15:37                locales                                                     
da----        08-Jun-17     16:38                node_modules                                                
da----        05-Jun-17     15:37                public                                                      
da----        08-Jun-17     16:33                scripts                                                     
da----        12-Jun-17     15:27                src                                                         
da----        05-Jun-17     15:37                test                                                        
-a----        08-Jun-17     16:52            841 .eslintrc.json                                              
-a----        06-Jun-17     23:31            434 .gitattributes                                              
-a----        05-Jun-17     15:37            306 .gitignore                                                  
-a----        08-Jun-17     16:51           2855 package.json                                                
-a----        12-Jun-17     16:22              0 print.txt                                                   
-a----        12-Jun-17     15:53          96996 README.md                                                   
-a----        05-Jun-17     15:37         236619 yarn.lock
```

I'm hosting & running Jenkins docker image in the AWS-ECS to build my Asp.net Core WebApi project into docker container then push to AWS-ECS.

I put "build.sh" file in WebApi repo (as above) & config as below

Jenkin server > Workspace name > Configure > Build > Execute section.

```
sh ./build.sh
```

Jenkin server > Workspace name > Configure > Source Code Management section.

`Repository URL: https://bitbucket.org/dev/WebApi.git`

`Repository URL: https://bitbucket.org/dev/WebUI.git`

Everytimes I commit code into WebApi project, Jenkins works fine, but when committing to WebUI project, the folder `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myjenkins workspace/` is cleaned up & can't find "build.sh"

How can I checkout multiple project into differrent folder & copy all files/folders in "WebUI/build" to "WebApi/wwwroot"?

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar issues I used the Multiple SCMs Plugin for Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but it is deprecated right now. Let me try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin